# Optstring options in getopt function

Tags: c, linux, getopt

I am making a command line "replace" which must looks like:

```
replace OPT Old_Word New_Word -- files_to_be_replaced
```

OPT can be:

```
-l
-f
-i
-b
```

The program must be able to handle strings starts with "-" and "--".
and this is from the CNU specification:
an element of argv that starts with "-" (and is not exactly "-" or "--") is an option element.
so it always returns invalid option if for example wrote in place of Old_Word "--Hello"

Is there a way to make my program handle "-" and "--"?

Comment: Use `getopt_long()`?

Comment: Mm. Are you intent on using `getopt` for this? Since the syntax is fairly trivial, it may be simpler to code by hand, based on the constraints from the question.

Comment: CNU or GNU?  If CNU, what's that short for?

Comment: Now you know why `-o Old_Word -n New_Word` would be a good idea (at least optionally including the `-o` and `-n` in case of words starting with dashes).

Comment: Can you have more than one of `-b`, `-f`, `-i`, `-l` in a single invocation of your command?  In most respects, that's not crucial.  Are you required to mandate the double dash where it is shown?  Would `replace -b -- Old_Word New_Word file1 …` be unacceptable?  What about `replace -f Old_Word New_Word file1 …`?  Note that `getopt()` does not tell you when the double-dash as 'end of options' has been processed; it just changes its behaviour thereafter.  That means if you must mandate the double-dash, you probably can't use regular `getopt()` (and I'm not sure about `getopt_long()` either!).